# MySql Sorting columns from 2 or more tables by date

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

```
comments:
id   /   comments    /   date
1        comment1     1389986953
2        comment2     1389986935


topics:
id   /   topics    /   date
1        topic1      1389986930
2        topic2      1389986940
```

How can i select all the rows from both tables and sort them by the date?
so it will look something like:

```
topic1
comment2
topic2
comment1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a `SELECT UNION`

Reference:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

```
(SELECT comments AS col, date FROM comments)
UNION
(SELECT topics AS col, date FROM topics)
ORDER BY date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use `UNION ALL` to combine the results of both tables, then wrap this to sort.

```
SELECT a.type 
FROM   (SELECT comments AS type, 
               date 
        FROM   comments 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT topics, 
               date 
        FROM   topics) a 
ORDER  BY a.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT comments AS mergedField, date
    FROM comments
    UNION ALL
    SELECT topics, date
    FROM topics) mergeTable
ORDER BY date ASC
```